# User installed python modules

Tags: python, linux, unix, pip

On Linux, how do I see the list of all python modules that are installed by a specific user.

Where does

```
pip install --user install <module>
```

install?

Is there a way to identify modules installed by a specific user using tools other than pip except the ones that are individually downloaded which could be anywhere?

Comment: In the future, please post multiple questions separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--user` switch, by default, installs into the [`site.USER_BASE` location](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE):

> Path to the base directory for the user site-packages. Can be `None` if `getuserbase()` hasn’t been called yet. Default value is `~/.local` for UNIX and Mac OS X non-framework builds, `~/Library/Python/X.Y` for Mac framework builds, and `%APPDATA%\Python` for Windows.

You can override this by setting the `PYTHONUSERBASE` environment variable, as detailed in the [*User installs”* section](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#user-installs) of the pip manual.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see all your python modules (and versions) like this ([docs here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze.html)):

```
C:\Users\joe>pip freeze
Cython==0.19.2
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.1
MDP==3.3
MarkupSafe==0.18
PIL==1.1.7
...
```

Looks like Mr. Pieters has answered your other question